# AWS: how to determine who deleted a Lambda trigger

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Since past week we recorded irregular deletions of the trigger of AWS Lambda.

We would like to find out when this exactly happened to determine the reason/cause of deletion. We tried looking for the entries in Cloudtrail, but not sure what to look for exactly ?

How to find the root cause and reasons for the deletion ?

Comment: Can you clarify which trigger?

Comment: the trigger will be activated, when a new file in a specific S3 bucket will be added

Comment: If you have CloudTrail enabled you should be able to search through the logs to find the API call.

Comment: Have you search in CT, using event name of `PutBucketNotification`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks Marcin and ydaetskcoR. We found the problem. The Lambda trigger is a property of the S3 bucket. We had different lambda trigger in different projects (with different terraform states). So every time one (terraform) project will be applied, the trigger of the other project will be overwritten, because the terraform state is not aware of it. We saw PutBucketNotifications in cloudtrail,but didn't recognize the connections...

Answer (score 0):

You can troubleshoot operational and security incidents over the past 90 days in the CloudTrail console by viewing Event history. You can look up events related to creation, modification, or deletion of resources. To view Events in logs follow this ;
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/get-and-view-cloudtrail-log-files.html